# Track the login event with Google Analytics in a WordPress website

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-analytics

I wish to track when a user log in their account in my WordPress website with GA4 (Google Analytics 4), so I used the hook 'wp_login', as you can see in the snippet below that I added to functions.php file, but it doesn't work. I tried the hook alone (to create a cookie) and it works fine and I tried the code inside the function 'gal' alone and it works fine.

```
add_action('wp_login', 'gal',90);
function gal(){
    echo "<script>dataLayer.push({event: 'login'});</script>";
}
```

Comment: Did you check where in the generated page source code this script actually ends up? I'm guessing that it will probably get output very much "at the top", before the GA4 script is even loaded, let alone initialized - so that your script probably doesn't find any `dataLayer` array that it could push anything to. Did you check if the browser console has anything to say in that regard?

Comment: I checked the browser console and no javascript error appears, but as soon as the user login they is redirect to another page (their account dashboard), so maybe an error messagge is lost in the login page. I didn't find the line <script>dataLayer.push({event: 'login'});</script> in the page where the user is redirect after login.

Comment: There should be an option "preserve log" (or similar, depending on browser/language), so that error messages are _not_ thrown away when navigating to a different page. And I asked you something else as well.

Comment: I didn't know there was a "preserve log" option. It is very useful and I thank you so much. Unfortunately even using "preserve log" option no JavaScript error appears in console. Related to the other question you asked ("Did you check where in the generated page source code this script actually ends up?") I thought I answered that by telling you that "I didn't find the line <script>dataLayer.push({event: 'login'});</script> in the page where the user is redirect after login" but maybe I didn't understand the question properly or I didn't look in the right place?

Answer (score 0):

yea... You should probably use cookies to do this. Something like:

```
function set_logged_in_cookie(){
    if(is_user_logged_in()){
    
        if(!isset($_COOKIE['logged_in_once'])) {
            setcookie( 'logged_in_once', true, time()+DAY_IN_SECONDS, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN ); //if there is no cookie set one.
            // time() is the time now + a day in seconds

            //now lets push an event to Google Analytics
        ?>
        <script>
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            window.dataLayer.push({
                'event': 'login'
            });
        </script>
    <?php
        }
    }
}

add_action('init', 'set_loggedin_cookie');
```

NB. Be careful when you are setting Cookies. It should be before any headers are sent or html has been rendered.
This should fire only once, depending on how long you want the cookie to remain.
ref https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: The answer looks OK, however, it could be improved with a little explanation of what you are doing and why, to go together with the code you provided.

Additionally, as a side comment, checking for is_admin() does not check for the current logged in user's role. The code is different for that. And if you are using is_admin() to check if you are in the backend, it is not a sufficient check in itself to determine that.

Comment: The codes you suggested doesn't work (the cookie is created but the event login ins't sent to GA4). I believe the problem is about the js script that send the event.